# How can I make the parent class constructor run before the child's constructor? (PHP)

Tags: php

How can I make the parent constructor run before the child's constructor?
( Code: )

```
class database{
    public function __construct(){
        // Connect to database
    }
}

class child extends database{
    public function __construct(){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I want it to connect to the database and then run the child's constructor, is that possible?

Comment: `function __construct() { parent::__construct(); /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 6):

Add `parent::__construct()` to the start of the child `__construct()`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class child extends database{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // Do something
    }
}
```